# WooCommerce Dynamic Cart Pricing

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

I needed to calculate the price of a typeface based on the 3 different licence values selected. I couldn't find a way of doing this with variations unless I created a variation for each possible combination which would be insane!

So I opted to calculate the price using the `woocommerce_before_calculate_totals` hook.

I created the two functions below which all seems to work fine. The correct price is set and charged. Except randomly some customers find themselves being charged multiples of the expected final price. Sometimes up to 6 times the expected price.

I know there are a lot of variables here, but would any one have any idea why this might be? Mike Jolley hinted that the hook can run multiple times and to set a custom prop to resolve but I haven't had any success trying. I also can't recreate the problem locally so it's proving incredibly tricky to resolve!

If anyone could shed any light or possible avenues to explore that would be amazing!

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price' );
function add_custom_price( $cart_object ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
    return;

    if (WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() > 0):

        // Licence values chosen from omsetype.co buying module e.g. 1:10000:2500 must have at least one value
        $multiplier_desktop = ! empty(WC()->session->get('licence')) ? WC()->session->get('licence') : 0;
        $multiplier_web = ! empty(WC()->session->get('licence_web')) ? WC()->session->get('licence_web') : 0;
        $multiplier_app = ! empty(WC()->session->get('licence_app')) ? WC()->session->get('licence_app') : 0;

        foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ):
            if ($value['data']->is_type('variation')):
                $price = mttd_return_price($multiplier_desktop, $multiplier_web, $multiplier_app, $value['data']);
                $value['data']->set_price($price);
            endif;
        endforeach;

    endif;
}



/**
 * Return price
 **/
function mttd_return_price($multiplier_desktop, $multiplier_web, $multiplier_app, $product) {
    $price = 0;
    $price_base = $product->get_price();
    $price_division_web = get_field('price_division_web', 'options'); // 100
    $price_division_app = get_field('price_division_app', 'options'); // 50

    if (!empty($multiplier_desktop) && $multiplier_desktop > 0):
        $price += $price_base * sqrt(floatval($multiplier_desktop));
    endif;
    if (!empty($multiplier_web) && $multiplier_web > 0):
        $price += ($price_base * sqrt(floatval($multiplier_web))) / $price_division_web;
    endif;
    if (!empty($multiplier_app) && $multiplier_app > 0):
        $price += ($price_base * sqrt(floatval($multiplier_app))) / $price_division_app;
    endif;

    return $price;
}
```