# Adding price to woocommerce cart item with get_price gets multiplied with 3?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Similar question: [WooCommerce Dynamic Cart Pricing](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/291814/woocommerce-dynamic-cart-pricing)

```
function odb_add_length_price( $cart_object ) {
    if( !(is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX'))) {
        foreach ( $cart_object->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
            $price = $cart_item['data']->get_price();

            $price = 1 + $price;

            $cart_item['data']->set_price( $price ); 
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'odb_add_length_price', 10, 1);
```

If the product price is set to 100, then the total should be 101. The price returned is set to 103, for some reason it gets multiplied by 3.

If i remove the $price and set a static value to 100, the returned price is 101.

If i only return the price, the prices returns as 100.

So each time i combine or calculate get_price plus x, it multiplies by 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add `remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'odb_add_length_price', 10, 1);` on the first line in the function.

This removes the function each time it run and works like expected.